# iPhone X or Canon 77D - which will produce better quality?

Tags: dslr, iphone

I own a Canon 77D DSLR and am just getting started with filmmaking. I have a variable ND filter etc. I wonder if this DSLR would produce better quality videos than my iPhone X (with FiLMiC pro)?

I know that 77D doesn't shoot in 4K whereas iPhone X does. But what about the quality of 1080p at 24fps?

iPhone X also seems to have some optical image stabilization. Is it better than Canon's electronical stabilizer for videos in Digic 7 chip?

I don't know much about codecs and stuff hence why I ask here.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this hardly depends on what you want to do and need.
If you simply want to create cinematic images, 77D will be a lot better because of the bigger sensor.

If you need highly technical and sharp images, like I would expect it from a tech YT channel, I would take the iPhone X.

In the end, it matters more how you handle the camera, than what it can.
Espacially lighting will make a huge difference on both cameras.

So facts are, iPhone X video will look cleaner, but 77D will be more easily to achieve cinematic footage and give character to the image

Comment: Thanks! From what I already observed: the iPhone X footage looks terrible in low light whereas from a 77D looks relatively good. But I guess you can’t cheat physics - sensor size matters a lot in low light.

Comment: I don't have practical test with the 77D, but that may be very true. A bigger sensor generally means better night capabilitys, but there are some other factors as well.